# Writing a docs topic tag in the markdown for a regular site answer

Tags: support, feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

I can write `[tag:excel-vba]` in the markdown for an answer and get [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba). However, if I am referring to the Documentation site, I do not want it to link to this,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba

I want it to link to this,

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/topics.

Has this been addressed? The links that I have found on various pages are currently simple anchors with text.